# No value given for one or more required parameters. How do I fix it?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

I'm trying to make it so the user can search the datagridview for a certain value using a textbox (txtSearchDGV.text) by clicking (btnSearch).

However, on the line that reads:

```
da.Fill(ds, "tblOrders")
```

I receive an error stating "No value given for one or more required parameters"

Here are the declarations:

```
Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\SAC1 Database.mdb"
Dim MyConn As New OleDbConnection
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim tables As DataTableCollection
Dim source1 As New BindingSource
Dim dt As DataTable
Dim SelectedTable As String
```

And here is the code in which the error occurs when clicking the button:

```
Private Sub QueryDGV()

    '   IF THE SELECTED TABLE IS TBLORDERS AND ADMIN DETAILS ARE TRUE
    If lbxTables.SelectedItem = "tblOrders" And frmLogin.AdminDetails = True Then

        '   ASSIGN TABLE NAME
        SelectedTable = "tblOrders"

        '   CREATE BINDINGSOURCE, DATASET AND TABLES
        Dim source1 As New BindingSource
        Dim ds = New DataSet
        Dim tables = ds.Tables

        '   OPEN CONNECTION AND ASSIGN CONNECTION STRING
        Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\SAC1 Database.mdb")
        cn.Open()

        '   CREATE DA COMMAND AND SQL STATEMENT, RUN
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select * from [tblOrders] where [ID] OR [ProductName] OR [Quantity] OR [PriceEach] OR [TotalPricePerLine] OR [OrderTotalPrice] OR [Username] LIKE '[" & txtSearchDGV.Text & "]'", cn)
        da.SelectCommand = cmd

        '   FILL THE TABLE AND DATAGRIDVIEW
        da.Fill(ds, "tblOrders")
        Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
        source1.DataSource = view
        dgvDynamic.DataSource = view

        '   CLOSE THE CONNECTION
        cn.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Thank you, I appreciate it.

Comment: Thats still not how to compose SQL and that not how an `OR` clause works.  See www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/

Comment: You learn how to write Boolean expressions. We might say things like "if A or B = Z" in plain English but that's not how mathematics or logic work, so it's not how programming works. You're still going to have issues with that query even then but that will alleviate that specific issue.

Comment: I am guessing that when the user clicks the button to search and the `QueryDGV()` method is called, that there is currently “data” already in the grid. I am guessing since it would be difficult for the user to search for something in a grid that has no data. Therefore, I assume that the `BindingSource` `source1` originally contains ALL the data and is used as a `DataSource` to the currently displayed `DataGridView`. If this is the case, then it may be easier to simply filter the `BindingSource` and eliminate the query to the database. Have you considered filtering the `BindingSource` instead?

Comment: @JOhnG Yes you're right, data is already set in the datagridview when the method is called. How do you filter the binding source based on what is in the textbox? Thanks heaps.

Comment: A google search for “vb.net binding source filter tutorial” should return plenty of examples. The filter property has some limitations; however, it should work as a simple filter to the grid. Try something and post it if you cannot get it working.

Comment: What I find odd is that there is only one text box to search from AND the (awkward) query code appears to check to see if the text in the text box is “LIKE” the “ID” column or “ProductName”, etc.…  This seems odd and I have nothing but sympathy for the poor user trying to search for something. Example, let us say the user wanted to filter the “ID” column to display only records with “ID = 10”. Let us further assume that there are no records where ID = 10, but there are numerous records such that “ProductName” = “Power 10 Super drill YY”. This may be confusing to the user.

Comment: My point is that, if the user can type into a text box to filter the displayed records, the user is going to have to know what column in the grid the filter text box is referring to. In addition, with only one text box you force the user to construct a query string if multiple column filters are wanted.

Comment: To make this “filter/search” user friendly, one possible solution is to make a filter text box for each column you want to be filtered. There would be a filter text box for the UserName, ID, ProductName… etc. This will make it easier to construct the filter string and will be user friendly. This will allow for multi-filter situations. Example, the user wanted to filter by username and price over $100.

Comment: Lastly, using a `BindingSource`, you could construct a filter string that would look something like `Dim filterString = string.Format("UserName LIKE '%{0}%' and ProductName LIKE '%{1}%' ", textBoxFilterUserName.Text, textBoxFilterProductName.Text);` Then, apply the filter string to the `BindingSource` with `source1.Filter = filterString`

Answer (score 0):

The condition in your sql query is wrong. It should be written like this:

```
Select * 
from [tblOrders] 
where [ID] LIKE ''
      OR [ProductName]  LIKE ''
      OR [Quantity]  LIKE ''
      OR [PriceEach]  LIKE ''
      OR [TotalPricePerLine]  LIKE ''
      OR [OrderTotalPrice]  LIKE ''
      OR [Username] LIKE ''
```

As a sidenote, your query is vulnerable with SQL injection. You must paramaterized your sql query to avoid from it.

```
Dim sqlString AS String = "Select * " _
    & " from [tblOrders]  " _
    & " where [ID] LIKE @param  " _
    & "       OR [ProductName]  LIKE @param " _
    & "       OR [Quantity]  LIKE @param " _
    & "       OR [PriceEach]  LIKE @param " _
    & "       OR [TotalPricePerLine]  LIKE @param " _
    & "       OR [OrderTotalPrice]  LIKE @param " _
    & "       OR [Username] LIKE @param " 
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlString , cn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", txtSearchDGV.Text)
```

Comment: Hey I used your second lot of code, thanks heaps for your response. No errors occur, but the datagridview appears blank when searching for anything. Thanks!

Comment: @EthanPayne try this line when supplying value in the parameter: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", "*" + txtSearchDGV.Text + '*')`

Comment: Thanks again, still the datagridview is blank. Thanks heaps.